# talend convert rows to columns

Tags: xml, talend

i need to read fields from an xml file.

XML is like:

```
<fieldlist>
<field name "foo" value="1"/>
<field name "bar" value="2"/>
<field name "baz" value="3"/>
<field name "empty" value=""/>
</fieldlist>
```

With FileInputXML and tXML_Map i can already filter out empty values.

But now i need the all values by name in a single action.

How can i get those? I need it like
|foo|bar|baz|
|1|2|3|

Or on variables foo=1, bar=2, baz=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using xslt component

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;Values&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="fieldlist">
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/Values&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```